# Ventana modal en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito hacer una ventana modal en `swift`.

El código que tengo en el controlador que lanza el modal es este:

```
if segue.identifier == "modal" {
   let vc = segue.destination as! ModalViewController
   vc.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
}
```

Pero me ocupa la pantalla completa

Quiero que quede algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como ésto:

**En tu MainController.swift:**

```
func showModal() {
    let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    presentViewController(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**En tu ModalViewController.swift:**

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        view.opaque = false
    }
}
```

**Si estás trabajando con storyboard**

Añade el Storyboard Seque con la opción `Present Modally` a tu ModalViewController y añade los siguientes valores:

```
Background = Clear Color
Drawing = Desactiva the Opaque checkbox
Presentation = Over Current Context
```

Asegúrate de que el segue sólo utiliza el valor `DEFAULT` para la presentación y la transición. El uso del contexto actual para la presentación hace que el modo se vuelva negro en lugar de permanecer transparente.

Comment: Esta respuesta no resuelve el problema de la pregunta